# Can't boot up macOS system nor reinstall/format it

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, bootable-disk

I'm stuck here with a strange situation.
When I turn on my macbook pro 13 m1, I can't select the system to boot up with. Nothing pops up, can't run it in a safe mode. When I go to the disk utility after holding the power button, there is no free space, meaning I can't format it, however all the partitions seems to be viewed in this area.
I think I tried everything I can think of.

Help needed!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you select "Show All Devices" from the "View" menu.

Comment: Did you do anything that might have caused this, like try to erase and reinstall the OS? Any chance that you can take this to an Apple Store?

Comment: @benwiggy sry for the late reply. Yes, I tried to erase it, but the process didn't go well. It just turned off during it, so I guess that's the reason why it's failed.

Unfortunately, there's no such places at my location. I was told that the only option is to change SSD to a new one. However, I still hope there is something that can be done before doing something radical like that

Comment: @DavidAnderson this option is already turned on in my screenshot, so doesn't show much. I tried to look up all the partitions through terminal. It was like it shows full and empty space at the same time under different disk numbers.
I also tried to connect it to another mac and run Apple Configurator 2, etc. unfortunately, it doesn't detect any external device.

Comment: I have no experience with Apple Silicon so my suggestions may not work. I would plug in an external SSD, erase the external drive, then try installing Montgomery on the external drive. This may require changing the security settings to allow external drive booting. BTW, I do not think you can change the internal SSD to a new one. In other words, I believe the internal SSD can not be replaced.